# How to solve: ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi in Apache2 log?

Tags: python, django, wsgi, synology

I get "ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi" in my Apache2 log, when trying to run a Django site. When I do run the wsgi.py from command line or try to import django.core.wsgi in a python command line everything just works fine. What could be the source of this problem?

Comment: Do you have a subdirectory named django in your repo?

Comment: I checked, but there is no folder called "django" within my project folder. So no collision there ..

Comment: are you using a virtualenv?

Comment: No, I'm trying to make this work on a Syonlogy NAS.

Comment: Could you add your Apache config and WSGI script contents to the question?

Answer (score 2):

This is usually because your mod_wsgi installation is compiled against and using a different Python installation/version than what you want to use and which you installed Django into.

Go through:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation

and validate what Python installation/version mod_wsgi is using.